# Localize Unix Time Value Using Moment.js + jQuery Datatables w/ pagination

Tags: pagination, datatables, momentjs

I'm using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and [jquery datatables](https://datatables.net/). Specifically, I have a a list of cells that all contain a Unix Timestamp.

What I'd like to do is convert this timestamp to the user's localized time (based on his/her timezone).

I am able to get the timezone to localize, but it only works for the first group of paginated results in my table...if I navigate to another page, the timestamp still shows up as the raw unix value.

I've made a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5z8xhzn/) to illustrate.

Could someone kindly let me know 1) if there's a better way to do what I'm doing 2) how I can localize my times even after actions like a) searching the table 2) sorting the table 3) paginating the table?

Huge thanks in advance!

**My JS:**

```
// Do Datatables
$('.my-datatable').DataTable({
    "order": [[ 1, 'desc' ],],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] } 
    ]
});

// Loop through class to localize unix time based on user's time zone
function localizeTime(){
    $( ".localize_time" ).each(function() {
        if (typeof moment !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(moment)) {
            var userMomentTz         = moment().format("Z");
            var userTimeZone         = userMomentTz.replace(":", "");
            var elementSiteUnixTimeText  = $(this).find('.localize_time_unix').text();
            var elementSiteUnixTimeVal   = parseInt(elementSiteUnixTimeText.trim());
            if (userTimeZone.substring(0, 1) == "-") {
                var userTimeZoneHr  = parseInt(userTimeZone.substring(1,3));
                var userTimeZoneMin = parseInt(userTimeZone.slice(-2));
                var userTimeOffset  = (userTimeZoneHr + '.' + (userTimeZoneMin/60))*(-1);
            } else {
                var userTimeZoneHr = parseInt(userTimeZone.substring(0,2));
                var userTimeZoneMin = parseInt(userTimeZone.slice(-2));
                var userTimeOffset  = userTimeZoneHr + '.' + (userTimeZoneMin/60);
            }
            var momentDateUserOffset = moment.unix(elementSiteUnixTimeVal).utcOffset(userTimeOffset);
            var momentDateFormattedOffset = moment(momentDateUserOffset).format('ddd, D MMM YYYY, h:mm A');
            $(this).find('.localize_time_display').text(momentDateFormattedOffset);
        };
    });
};

// Run time localization function
if ( $( ".localize_time" ).length ) {
    localizeTime()
};
```

**My HTML**

```
<table class="my-datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Stuff</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Stuff</td>
            <td>
                <span class="localize_time">
                    <span class="localize_time_unix">UNIX Time n++</span>
                    <span class="localize_time_display"></span>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Add your function call on the drawCallback of the DataTable or, even better, add a render function the relevant columns.

Comment: Thanks @annoyingmouse. I just posted an answer that uses data rendering and seems to be working decently enough.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well fortunately this was easier than I thought using ['data rendering'](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers)

Working [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hk1a7dd/)

Hope this helps someone!

**My updated JS**

```
// Do Datatables
$('.my-datatable').DataTable( {
    "order": [[ 1, 'desc' ],],
    "columnDefs": [{
    "targets": 1,
        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
            if (typeof moment !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(moment)) {
                var userMomentTz         = moment().format("Z");
                var userTimeZone         = userMomentTz.replace(":", "");
                var elementSiteUnixTimeText  = data;
                var elementSiteUnixTimeVal   = parseInt(elementSiteUnixTimeText.trim());
                if (userTimeZone.substring(0, 1) == "-") {
                    var userTimeZoneHr  = parseInt(userTimeZone.substring(1,3));
                    var userTimeZoneMin = parseInt(userTimeZone.slice(-2));
                    var userTimeOffset  = (userTimeZoneHr + '.' + (userTimeZoneMin/60))*(-1);
                } else {
                    var userTimeZoneHr = parseInt(userTimeZone.substring(0,2));
                    var userTimeZoneMin = parseInt(userTimeZone.slice(-2));
                    var userTimeOffset  = userTimeZoneHr + '.' + (userTimeZoneMin/60);
                }
                var momentDateUserOffset = moment.unix(elementSiteUnixTimeVal).utcOffset(userTimeOffset);
                var momentDateFormattedOffset = moment(momentDateUserOffset).format('ddd, D MMM YYYY, h:mm A');
                $(this).find('.localize_time_display').text(momentDateFormattedOffset);
                return momentDateFormattedOffset;
            }; 
        }
    }]
} );
```